# Ticks not filtered in LineChart when ChartRangeFilter used

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

When I use ChartRangeFilter to filter my LineChart I suppose that ticks of LineChart that I set through hAxis.ticks will be also filtered but it not. All ticks on hAxis showed anyway if I try to scale chart with range filter. How can I solve this?

```
function draw_dashboard(data) {
var chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
   document.getElementById('dashboard'));

var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
 'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
 'containerId': 'control',
 'options': {
   // Filter by the date axis.
   'filterColumnIndex': 0,
   'ui': {
     'chartType': 'LineChart',
     'chartOptions': {
       'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
       'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
     },
     // 6 months in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 30 * 6 * 1000 = 15552000000
     'minRangeSize': 15552000000
   }
 }
});

var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
 'chartType': 'LineChart',
 'containerId': 'chart',
 'options': {
   // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
   'chartArea': {'height': '55%', 'width': '90%'},
   'legend': {'position': 'none'},
   'hAxis': {
     'slantedTextAngle': 90,
     'ticks': chart_data.getDistinctValues(0)
     'showTextEvery': 1
   }
 }
});

dashboard.bind(control, chart);
dashboard.draw(chart_data);
};
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of input data?

Comment: Did you try without `'ticks': chart_data.getDistinctValues(0)` option?

Comment: @AntoJurković input data it's two columns table. First column with dates, second with numbers. Ticks contains all dates. Yes I tried and scale works but some of dates hided.

Comment: @AntoJurković As example when I have 48 points (one point for each month within four years) and want to show all of them without ticks there are only two hAxis labels per year will be showed (Jan 2011, Jul 2011, Jan 2012, Jul 2012 and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the `hAxis.ticks` option, those values will *always* be present on the axis, regardless of the data that is passed to the chart (as the chart is unaware that the data is filtered in any way).  If you want to filter the ticks as well, you have to set up a `'statechange'` event handler for your filters that gets the filtered data and sets the `hAxis.ticks` option accordingly:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', function () {
    var filteredData = chart.getDataTable();
    chart.setOption('hAxis.ticks', filteredData.getDistinctValues(0));
    chart.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `hAxis.ticks` setting. If you use

```
ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0),
```

then `ticks` is set to an array which has the same length as length of input data. And you get tick marks for each month. Additionaly, using option:

```
showTextEvery: 1
```

that is just confirmed (How many horizontal axis labels to show, where 1 means show every label). You get label for each tick. And using filters there is no much change.

If you comment out `tick` option, labels at hAxis will be changed according to range of filtered data.